# Android layout-xml for styled View

Tags: android, android-layout

What's the best practice to create the View object with the predefined attributes ?

I'd like to use something like

```
View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.orangeview, container,
                false);
```

but it seems to require the orange view to be inside the view group and i'd prefer to have something more standalone inside the layout file - the only view attributes like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/orangeradiobutton"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/radiobutton_colors" />
```

Is that possible or should i use another approach ?

Comment: The container argument is used to 'size' your inflated layout. If you don't want this, you can just call View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orangeView, null);

Comment: @azgolfer yeah it works, please do it as an answer. My mistake was forgetting to update the group state where the orangeView was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container argument is used to 'size' your inflated layout. If you don't want this, you can just call

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orangeView, null);
```